# Check if a point is inside polygon in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

When I draw a polygon in an OpenLayers map, I want to know if the marker is inside the polygon or not. I searched in the OpenLayers API, but didn't find a solution.

[image: screenshot for visual clarification]

And you can see my full code in this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/iI92XbxVDAg97MNQt5JV?p=preview).

I have the impression that I have to modify this function:

```
  function addInteraction() {
    var value = typeSelect.value;
    if (value !== 'None') {
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: vectorSource,
      type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (typeSelect.value)
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    draw.on('drawend',function(e){
      //Here
    });
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have a method '[intersectsCoordinate](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Geometry-Geometry.html#intersectsCoordinate)' for the ol.geom.Geometry.

So the code for that will look like:

```
var polygonGeometry = e.feature.getGeometry();
var coords = iconFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
polygonGeometry.intersectsCoordinate(coords)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [JSTS](https://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/) library, which implements simple geometry processing such as `intersects`, `difference`, etc.  It contains an OL3 parser that allows the conversion of geometry from OL3 to JSTS and vice-versa.

See an [example in OL3](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html).  Basically, you would use a process that checks if the geometry of your marker is within your polygon or not and do what you want from there.