# Open Layers 5 containsXY not working. Check if a coordinate is in Polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers-5

I'm trying to check if a point is within a Polygon. This is my function:

```
import { containsXY } from 'ol/extent';

isInside(polygon, longitude, latitude) {
    polygon = JSON.parse(polygon); // Polygon is originally = JSON.stringify([[long1, lat1],[long2, lat2], ...])

    let poli = new Polygon(polygon);

    // Try 1: Not working
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli, latitude, longitude));
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli, longitude, latitude));
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli.getExtent(), latitude, longitude));
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli.getExtent(), longitude, latitude));

    // Try 2: Not working
    let coordinate = this.to3857([longitude, latitude]);
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli, coordinate[0],  coordinate[1]));
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli, coordinate[1], coordinate[0]));
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli.getExtent(), coordinate[0], coordinate[1]));
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli.getExtent(), coordinate[1], coordinate[0]));

    // Try 3: Not working
    coordinate = this.to4326([longitude, latitude]);
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli, coordinate[0], coordinate[1]));
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli, coordinate[1], coordinate[0]));
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli.getExtent(), coordinate[0], coordinate[1]));
    console.log("Result --> ", containsXY(poli.getExtent(), coordinate[1], coordinate[0]));
}
```

All results are `false`. How could I check if a coordinate is in Polygon? Nothing worked for me with OpenLayers API.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To determine if a `Point` geometry is in the `Polygon`'s bounds/extent use:

```
ol.extent.containsXY(polygon.getExtent(), coordinate[0], coordinate[1])
```

updated `isInside` function:

```
function isInside(polygon, longitude, latitude) {
  let coordinate = ol.proj.fromLonLat([longitude, latitude]);
  console.log("Result (in bounds) --> ", ol.extent.containsXY(polygon.getExtent(), coordinate[0], coordinate[1]));
}
```

To determine if a `Point` geometry is inside the `Polygon`'s (which is different from being inside the `Polygon`'s bounds/extent) use (from the related question: [Check if a point is inside polygon in OpenLayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446376/check-if-a-point-is-inside-polygon-in-openlayers-3)):

```
polygon.intersectsCoordinate(coordinate);
```

updated `isInside` function:

```
function isInside(polygon, longitude, latitude) {
    let coordinate = ol.proj.fromLonLat([longitude, latitude]);
    console.log("Result (in polygon) --> ", polygon.intersectsCoordinate(coordinate));
}
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.1.3_polygonContains.html)

[image: screenshot of marker inside polygon bounds but outside of polygon]

[image: screenshot of marker inside polygon itself]

**code snippet:**

```js
function isInside(polygon, longitude, latitude, text) {
  let coordinate = ol.proj.fromLonLat([longitude, latitude]);
  console.log("Result for " + text + " (in bounds) --> ", ol.extent.containsXY(polygon.getExtent(), coordinate[0], coordinate[1]));
  console.log("Result for " + text + " (in polygon) --> ", polygon.intersectsCoordinate(coordinate));
}

window.onload = function() {
  isInside(polygon, 106.8060388, -6.5971469, "black marker");
  isInside(polygon, 105.998544, -7.0553, "blue marker");
}

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([106.044189, -6.840865]),
    zoom: 7
  })
});

// modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210362/open-layers-3-how-to-draw-a-polygon-programmatically
var jsonData = [{
    lat: -5.896423,
    lng: 106.044189
  },
  {
    lat: -6.840865,
    lng: 105.192749
  },
  //{lat: -6.147714, lng: 106.972534},
  {
    lat: -6.813594,
    lng: 106.016724
  },
  {
    lat: -6.988102,
    lng: 106.516601
  },
  {
    lat: -7.36416,
    lng: 106.406738
  },
  {
    lat: -7.511228,
    lng: 107.450439
  },
  {
    lat: -6.093095,
    lng: 106.989014
  }
]
// A ring must be closed, that is its last coordinate
// should be the same as its first coordinate.
var ring = [];
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  ring.push([jsonData[i].lng, jsonData[i].lat]);
}
// A polygon is an array of rings, the first ring is
// the exterior ring, the others are the interior rings.
// In your case there is one ring only.
var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([ring]);
polygon.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

// Create feature with polygon.
var feature = new ol.Feature(polygon);
feature.set('name', 'polygon');

// Create vector source and the feature to it.
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

// Create vector layer attached to the vector source.
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

// Add the vector layer to the map.
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

var geoMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'geoMarker',
  name: 'insidePolygon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([106.8060388, -6.5971469]))
});
geoMarker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({ //CircleStyle({
    radius: 7,
    snapToPixel: false,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'black'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'black',
      width: 2
    })
  })
}));

vectorSource.addFeature(geoMarker);
var geoMarker1 = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'geoMarker',
  name: 'outsidePolygon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([105.998544, -7.0553]))
});
geoMarker1.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({ //CircleStyle({
    radius: 7,
    snapToPixel: false,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'blue'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'blue',
      width: 2
    })
  })
}));

vectorSource.addFeature(geoMarker1);

var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: tooltip,
  offset: [10, 0],
  positioning: 'bottom-left'
});
map.addOverlay(overlay);

function displayTooltip(evt) {
  var pixel = evt.pixel;
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
    return feature;
  });
  tooltip.style.display = feature ? '' : 'none';
  if (feature) {
    overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
    tooltip.innerHTML = feature.get('name');
  }
};

map.on('pointermove', displayTooltip);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.1.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="tooltip"></div>
```